# Filter activity log entries by day and time span with power shell

Tags: shell, powershell, filter, event-log

I have the following working power shell command:

```
Get-Eventlog -Logname system -Source user32 | Select TimeGenerated, EntryType, Message
```

However I only want entries from monday to friday and between 6am and 4pm. 
How can I filter those entries.

Thanks for your help.

TheVagabond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to create a date boundary:

```
Get-Eventlog -LogName system -Source user32 |
    Where-Object { $_.TimeGenerated.DayOfWeek -ge ([DayOfWeek]'Monday') -and $_.TimeGenerated.DayOfWeek -le ([DayOfWeek]'Friday') -and $_.TimeGenerated.Hour -ge 6 -and $_.TimeGenerated.Hour -lt 16 } |
    Select-Object TimeGenerated, EntryType, Message
```

Creating a date boundary may be more efficient, especially if you only wanted to go back for a few weeks, that would feed the Before and After parameters on Get-EventLog. Using Where-Object for that is less efficient.

Comment: How can I set the time limit from 6am to 4pm? Or is that not possible?

Comment: It is, sorry I missed it. Editing the command. On reflection the operator for before 4PM should be -lt rather than -le. Otherwise it takes you all the way to 4:59PM. Fixing that too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
Get-Eventlog -Logname system -Source user32 | `
    Where {$_.TimeGenerated.DayOfWeek -ge [DayOfWeek]::Monday `
      -and $_.TimeGenerated.DayOfWeek -le [DayOfWeek]::Friday `
      -and $_.TimeGenerated.Hour -ge 6 `
      -and $_.TimeGenerated.Hour -lt 16} | `
    Select TimeGenerated, EntryType, Message
```

If you want to be more precise:

```
Get-Eventlog -Logname system -Source user32 | `
    Where {$_.TimeGenerated.DayOfWeek -ge [DayOfWeek]::Monday `
      -and $_.TimeGenerated.DayOfWeek -le [DayOfWeek]::Friday `
      -and $_.TimeGenerated.TimeOfDay -ge [Timespan]::Parse('06:00') `
      -and $_.TimeGenerated.TimeOfDay -le [Timespan]::Parse('16:00')} | `
    Select TimeGenerated, EntryType, Message
```